# Using both netbeans and eclipse to edit a netbeans project

Tags: eclipse, ide, netbeans

Hi Netbeans is the default IDE at my workplace. I want to use Eclipse to edit the Netbeans projects. How easy or difficult is it to do this. Can someone outline the steps involved for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to import an existing project into Eclipse by:

```
File -> Import -> Choose General -> Existing Projects into Workspace
```

It won't pick up your Netbeans settings however.  You may need to set your project up manually in terms of a libraries, source location etc..

Alternatively, if you're using Maven and Eclipse [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) you should be able to import a Maven project and have it pick up most of the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Importing an eclipse project should be easy (for Netbeans 6.7): File->Import Project->Eclipse Project

Or create a 'project with existing sources' which is available for Java, ruby, ...